# How to prevent VSCode code runner extension from opening second code terminal when I run it

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

Whenever I use code runner to run my python file, it always creates a second code terminal to use, and whenever I delete that terminal, it just creates another one. How can I prevent this? Its pretty annoying, I've tried looking for solutions online but none of them work...

[image]

Comment: don't use Code Runner, I don't

Comment: you have some very strange monitor artifact

Comment: most likely it has not created the existing terminal, has no knowledge what its state is so it creates a new one. If you kill it Code Runner knows it is killed and creates a new one, After Code Runner creates a terminal kill the other one

Comment: @rioV8 thank you for the help, and I believe those artifacts are connected to some quality limitations of gifs. Also, what do you use instead of code runner?

Comment: read the Python doc pages for VSC, create a launch config and use F5 and Ctrl+F5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if you just delete all the terminals and run code runner, it solves the problem. Code runner probably doesn't know that there isn't an existing terminal already after you reload VSCode, so it creates another one.